# SQL View does not update after adding new column in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I manually update my SQL Management Studio view?

Comment: can you add your  create view code

Comment: Yes, you need to add it to the view as well if your view is not defined with a wildcard. Example of wildcard view: `CREATE VIEW dbo.vwStaff AS SELECT * FROM dbo.Staff`

Comment: Correct behavior. A view is not supposed to change if you add columns to the table(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add new column to view.

For example a view as below.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_test]
AS
SELECT        column1, column2
FROM            dbo.tbl1
```

If you add a new column to table and if you want to see in the this view , you must alter the view as below.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[view_test]
AS
SELECT        column1, column2,column3
FROM            dbo.tbl1
```

Comment: I have a view like SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1] plus some calculated columns, but when I added a new column which is not getting shown in the view.